# FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgresq"

Tags: postgresql, authentication, passwords

When I try to run my app on `http://localhost:3000` I get following error

```
 FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgresq".
```

Not sure what is the issue, because in `database.yml` file my password is correct:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: Dzeus
  encoding: unicode
  username: postgresq
  password: mypassword
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
```

I'm able to connect to the database via pg admin program using the same password. Yesterday it worked fine but today something changed and I'm getting this error. Could you please help?

Comment: The username _postgresq_ is probably incorrect.

Comment: is it not the same as in "database.yml" file?